# Restrict system calls inside docker container

Tags: docker, seccomp

How can I restrict any system call made inside a docker container. If the given process makes a system call it will be blocked. Or how can I use seccomp with docker.

Answer (score 5):

You can see more at "[Seccomp security profiles for Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9539c0a4022857f7d317894e24a0694f4b62bbaf/docs/security/seccomp.md)" (the eature is available only if the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_SECCOMP` enabled.)

The supoprt for docker containers will be in docker 1.10: see [issue 17142](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17142)

> allowing the Engine to accept a seccomp profile at container run time.
>   In the future, we might want to ship builtin profiles, or bake profiles in the images.

[PR 17989](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17989) has been merged.

> It allows for passing a seccomp profile in the form of:

```
{
     "defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
     "syscalls": [
         {
             "name": "getcwd",
             "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO"
         }
     ]
 }
```

> Example (based on [Linux-specific Runtime Configuration - seccomp](https://github.com/opencontainers/specs/blob/master/runtime-config-linux.md#seccomp)):

```
$ docker run --rm -it --security-ops seccomp:/path/to/container-profile.json jess/i-am-malicious
```

Comment: Thank you  but when I tried this command a error came saying                    Error response from daemon: Invalid --security-opt: "seccomp:unconfined"          And please tell me how to know that my kernel is configured with CONFIG_SECCOMP enable and if not how to enable it.

Comment: That would be with docker 1.10-rc1 only

Comment: But I have docker 1.9 and still having the same problem. Please help

Comment: My point is: this is only supported by docker 1.10, not 1.9. Try docker 1.10-beta1 which just got out.